# What roles does a postgresql database make use of?

Tags: postgresql, roles, restore, postgresql-12

I've created a backup of a database on one computer

```
postgres@machine1$ pg_dump mydb > mydb.dump.sql
```

and then, from a second computer, having created a mydb database, I restore it from the dump

```
postgres@machine2$ psql -d mydb -f mydb.dump.sql
```

The problem is that the restoration throws an error when it encounters a role that doesn't already exist on the target system.

Is there some way I can get a list of roles, on the source system, that mydb make some use of? Then, if it's not too many, I'll manually create any missing ones on the target before restoring the database.

I don't want all the roles on the source system as available via psql \du, pg_roles or pg_dumpall -r.The source system will potentially contain many more roles than mydb makes use of. I only want the roles referenced in some way by mydb. Each role has an id, I can see them via pg_roles, and I'm assuming that permissions granted to roles within any particular database reference those ids.

I'm using postgresql 12.

Comment: Check pg_roles: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens pg_roles gives all the roles known to the server. I want only those used by the single mentioned database.

Comment: You could check the system catalog, the many acl-columns like relacl in pg_class: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Roles are global to the database cluster you can use:

[pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html)

> -r
> --roles-only

> Dump only roles, no databases or tablespaces

This will extract a file of roles in a database cluster using a command like:

`pg_dumpall -r -f database_roles.sql`

You would need to add appropriate host, user and port parameters as needed. The user needs to have sufficient privileges to read the [pg_authid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-authid.html) which contains passwords.

Comment: It's not possible to somehow filter them down to the roles actually *used* (referenced) by a specific database?

Comment: No, because roles are global to the cluster and available for use by any database in the cluster. See [pg_authid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-authid.html) which is the superuser accessible system catalog or [pg_roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html) which is the publicly readable view(no password data).

Comment: @Bergi. Realized my previous comment referred to using `pg_dumpall`. The other way to tackle this would be to work from the database object end. That would involve looking up the objects in a database in the system catalogs and pulling out their ACL values and then looking for distinct roles. This is complicated by the fact a object has default privileges granted to the owner that do not show up in the ACL entries until a specific GRANT/REVOKE is done. I don't have code at hand that would do this, though you might be able to search for a solution.

Comment: I've extended the question a bit to specifically mention pg_dumpall. It's only the roles that the particular database uses that I need. Not all of them.

Comment: @twisted. See my previous comments to Bergi with regard to the feasibility of this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to determine which role is used in which database.

You could connect to the `postgres` database and run

```
BEGIN;  -- transaction
DROP ROLE maxi;
ROLLBACK;  -- undo changes
```

for each role.

If there is no error, the role doesn't own any objects and has no privileges granted in any database.

Otherwise, the error message will tell you which database have objects with dependencies on the role.